# Why does adb scans port range 5555 to 5585, if adb clients use port 5037 to communicate with the adb server

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, adb, port

I'm growing bud in Android app development and while studying I often come across ADB so I planned to refer to the documentation but just couldn't grasp the concept-
I'm facing the following doubts-
1. What is a adb daemon(adbd).
2. I read about clients in the documentation, so are logcat,emulator or any android phone all clients.
3. Please correct me if I'm wrong- "ADB server runs on our PC/Development machine on port 5307, and for this it opens port 5307 of our OS(Windows in my case).
4.(MAIN QUESTION) The [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) says that **" When the server starts, it binds to local TCP port 5037 and listens for commands sent from adb clients—all adb clients use port 5037 to communicate with the adb server. "** 
 and it contradicts this by saying that 
**" It locates emulator/device instances by scanning odd-numbered ports in the range 5555 to 5585, the range used by emulators/devices. "**

If clients use port 5037 to connect to adb service running at port 5037 then why does it locate devices in the range 5555 to 5585.
 I'm badly confused regarding this.
Kindly help me clarify this concept.

Comment: There is no contradiction. there are 3 parts of `adb`. The `5037` port is used for communication between the `server` and `client`. The `5555-5583` port range could be used for communication between the `server` and `daemon` (in case of emulator or a device connected via wifi).

Comment: Ohh. Then what is client in this archetecture ?